# Transpose columns to rows SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using this query:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(MAX([WM Week])) WKDate
   ,SUM(CAST(CAST([Sat Qty] AS DECIMAL(12, 5)) AS INT)) [Sat Qty]
   ,SUM(CAST(CAST([Sun Qty] AS DECIMAL(12, 5)) AS INT)) [Sun Qty]
   ,SUM(CAST(CAST([Mon Qty] AS DECIMAL(12, 5)) AS INT)) [Mon Qty]
   ,SUM(CAST(CAST([Tue Qty] AS DECIMAL(12, 5)) AS INT)) [Tue Qty]
   ,SUM(CAST(CAST([Wed Qty] AS DECIMAL(12, 5)) AS INT)) [Wed Qty]
   ,SUM(CAST(CAST([Thu Qty] AS DECIMAL(12, 5)) AS INT)) [Thu Qty] 
   ,SUM(CAST(CAST([Fri Qty] AS DECIMAL(12, 5)) AS INT)) [Fri Qty]
FROM 
    [dbo].[s_Validation]
```

To get this info:

[image]

But I need to get something like this:

```
WKDate        |  Dayname | Value
--------------+----------+--------
201749.00000  |  Sat Qty | 8978
201749.00000  |  Sun Qty | 5251
201749.00000  |  Mon Qty | 0
201749.00000  |  Tue Qty | 2653
201749.00000  |  Wed Qty | 2186
201749.00000  |  Thu Qty | 2201
201749.00000  |  Fri Qty | 2232
```

I am using the following query but I do not know hot to sum the data in the pivot sentence

```
SELECT 
    [WM Week], WKDate, Value
FROM 
    [dbo].[s_Validation]
UNPIVOT
   (Value FOR WKDate IN 
      ([Sat Qty], [Sun Qty], [Mon Qty], [Tue Qty], [Wed Qty], [Thu Qty], [Fri Qty])
)AS unpvt;
```

Comment: Can you share screen shot of your source data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to approach unpivoting using `APPLY`.  The rest is just simple aggregation:

```
SELECT w.[WM Week], v.which, SUM(v.value)
FROM dbo.s_SellThru_WMT_Validation w OUTER APPLY
     (VALUES ('Sat', [Sat Qty]),
             ('Sun', [Sun Qty]),
             ('Mon', [Mon Qty]),
             ('Tue', [Tue Qty]),
             ('Wed', [Wed Qty]),
             ('Thu', [Thu Qty]),
             ('Fri', [Fri Qty])
     ) v(which, amt)
GROUP BY [WM Week], v.which;
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and is much easier to do than UNPIVOT. I get a lot of report data to consume and this will come in handy.